# How to kill background processes upon interruption to the main tcl script?

Tags: tcl, interrupt, exit, exit-code

I have a tcl script (main.tcl), which kicks 2 other scripts to run in the background.

When main.tcl is interrupted using ctrl+c, the jobs launched by this script are not killed before exit.
Launching subprocesses like this: exec  &

What is the best way to kill all the jobs started by main.tcl, before this script is exited?

I am using tcl 8.5, not using any other packages(like tclx etc.,)

Comment: How _exactly_ are you launching the subprocesses? Is it `exec`, `exec &` or `open |` or what?

Comment: Launching subprocesses like this: exec &

Comment: `exec your/process &`return the `pid`, depending on your OS you can kill by `pid`

Comment: @Mkn I am trying to auto kill the background jobs launched by the main script